# How do I expose a C# Web API method to any calling origin?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, webapi

I have a C# Web API with this method (in its entirety):

```
public JsonResult PlanItems(string sessionId)
{
    Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    DTDBDataService svc = new DTDBDataService(_db);
    VM.PlanItems = svc.GetPlanItems(VM.User);

    return Json(VM.PlanItems);
}
```

I have a decoupled Angular client that makes this call to the api:

```
this.http.get<[DTPlanItem]>(url).subscribe( data => {
    console.log("Plan items: ", data); 

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        console.log(data[i]);
        this.planItems.push(data[i]);
    }

    console.log("Loaded items: ", this.planItems);
});
```

When running in dev (localhost), the client calling from `http://localhost:4200` uses this url:

```
https://localhost:44324/Planner/PlanItems?sessionId=e829fb5c-aa6d-43c9-99e7-0552afd8bc7e.
```

When the Web API is deployed, the client (still calling from `http://localhost:4200`) use this url:

```
https://7822-54268.el-alt.com/Planner/PlanItems?sessionId=8d240409-09ba-4d9d-914a-7c0031fd8a6b.
```

The deployed API results in an error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://7822-54268.el-alt.com/Planner/PlanItems?sessionId=4207b27d-7f65-4289-beb5-8ae35c7c5da3' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

It can't be unusual to deploy a Web API with the expectation that the clients will be calling from any, unknown domain. How do I expose a C# Web API method to any calling origin? This can't be an unusual situation. There are an uncountable number of Web APIs that are allowable from a cross origin. How is it done?

Comment: _"It can't be unusual to deploy a webapi with the expectation that the clients will be calling from any, unknown domain"_ - Note that CORS is enforced by the browser, not the server. Non-browser clients aren't affected by CORS. In browsers, it's intended to be a security feature. Anyway, you can refer to the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/december/asp-net-web-api-cors-support-in-asp-net-web-api-2) (or [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0) if your question is mistagged and you're using ASP.NET Core).

Comment: You might want to use the dev tool (typically via F12) to see if the response from https://7822-54268.el-alt.com contains the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header or not. If it is not presented then at least it tells you that the header added by  `Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` might be removed by something and you can check what else is touching the response header.

Comment: @victor6510 I suspect OP's issue is that they haven't also implemented the OPTIONS request that comes before the GET request. That's all solved by using the appropriate CORS configuration on the server, so that it handles both.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar The header setting the content-type was added because originally content-type was not being specified, and the default for get is something like application/json. and the documentation says that to avoid CORS, a request should be one of three specific types-one of which is text/plain. I confirmed in dev console that the content-type is being submitted as text/plain. But that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @victor6510 I confirmed that the response was coming back with "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Comment: If you're using Chrome, if I remember correctly, * isn't accepted by the browser when the header comes back. It has to be the same as the [`Origin` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) sent by the browser. The OPTIONS request for the same endpoint should also return the same header. Again, use the `EnableCorsAttribute` (as per my answer), configure it for the entire application, or use the `DisableCorsAttribute`.

Answer (score 2):

## What is CORS? Why do we use it?

> It can't be unusual to deploy a webapi with the expectation that the clients will be calling from any, unknown domain.

I'm going to start with this because I sense there might be some misunderstanding here. Although the server can influence CORS by way of headers, it's primarily a security feature of the browser, and is enforced by the browser.

Generally APIs not intended as backends for a browser-based frontend will be accessed with HTTP client libraries, which have no reason to implement CORS. As such, these don't need to concern themselves with configuring CORS and the clients will just work.

If you're creating a frontend and it's on the same host as the backend API, then CORS will not be an issue because there are no cross-origin requests. That is to say, if the page making the request is at https://www.example.com/frontend, and it's making a request to https://www.example.com/api/login then this will succeed without any additional configuration as they're both on https://www.example.com.

CORS applies when your frontend is on a different host to the API. This is a security feature.

Consider this scenario:

- Your frontend allows you to launch intercontinental nukes, but you have to first log in with a username and password.
- When you log in, the backend generates a session cookie for you, and your browser automatically uses that for subsequent requests.
- CORS doesn't exist.

Unfortunately, a bad actor has befriended you and sends you a link to a website with funny cat videos. What you don't realise is that website actually has a script running on it. That script makes a request to your Nukes API, requesting that it launch a nuke.

Without CORS (if it didn't exist), or with excessively permissive CORS rules, your browser will happily make this request using your existing session cookie from the Nukes frontend. This is very bad. CORS allows you to configure what origins (essentially websites) the browser should allow to make requests to your API. You can control what verbs (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.) are allowed, what headers are allowed, whether credentials can be used, etc. This allows you to ensure that malicious scripts running on other websites can't impersonate your users against your API.

When a browser makes an AJAX request, it will first call the endpoint with the OPTIONS verb, and get the CORS rules for that endpoint. Next it will make the actual request to that endpoint, once again validating the CORS rules in the response (although after the request has been processed by the server).

## How do I configure CORS?

You can use the [`EnableCorsAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn308848(v=vs.118)), which can be placed on an individual controller method, or on the controller class as a whole:

```cs
[EnableCors("https://localhost:55912",       // Origin
          "Accept, Origin, Content-Type", // Request headers
          "PUT",                          // HTTP methods
          PreflightMaxAge=600             // Preflight cache duration
)]
public HttpResponseMessage Put(Resource data)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
}
```

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/december/asp-net-web-api-cors-support-in-asp-net-web-api-2#cors-support-in-web-api-2)

Or you can configure it at the application level:

```cs
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
    // Other configuration omitted
        config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*")); // origins, request headers, methods
    }
}
```

More fine-grained approaches are also described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/december/asp-net-web-api-cors-support-in-asp-net-web-api-2#cors-support-in-web-api-2).

There's also [`DisableCorsAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn308846(v=vs.118)) that can be applied to a controller action or a controller class to disable CORS for that action or controller. Please bear in mind the security implementations of using this if you choose to.

Comment: Thanks for the help. By way of explanation, this api is configured to use CORS generally, but this particular method should be accessible by any origin. (Thus adding "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" to this specific method's response.) However, it appears that having CORS enabled in the API triggers a preflight check by the browser, which does not consider modifications that may be made in a specific method, but instead get a preflight response based on the global api config. Decorating the method with [DisableCors] addresses that situation.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, 8 days into this, I have a definitive answer.

If one want a C# WebApi endpoint to be exposed to any origin, one needs to have this in the header:
[image]

The most certain way to do this is by adding something like this to the controller methods that need to accommodate any origin:

```
            if (!cResponse.Headers.Keys.Contains("Access-Control-Allow-Origin")) 
                Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

The "best" way is a matter of opinion. This can be a line in the method. It can be in the method attributefilters. (I do it in OnActionExcuting with an ActionFilterAttribute.)

***Some important things.***

[DisableCors] may work. But it may not. Implementations of this decoration do not work everywhere. (I don't know why.)

***Calls need to be sequential, and not async***. I know. But if the processing thread switches to a thread from the same origin after you have set the header, and then comes back the Response Header gets reset to whatever was in the original Request. So, async calls run the risks of "stomping" on your Access-Control-Allow-Origin header entry.